# Como actualizar el precio total de todos los productos al eliminar un producto

Tags: flutter, dart

Ocupo actualizar el precio total del carrito cuando se llama la función eliminar producto al eliminar un producto de el. Lo que hace mi código ahorita es que al presionar el botón para eliminar un producto de una lista este actualiza la lista de manera inmediatamente pero el precio no y la manera en que  se   actualiza el precio es al cambiar de pantalla y regresar al carrito y si comento la la funciona de eliminar si me actualiza y guarda   el precio total de todos los productos       .aaaaaaaa

```
class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  double subTotalCart = 0.00;
  Future<List<Product>> cartData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cartData= fetchCartData();
  }

  Future<List<Product>> fetchCartData() async {
    List<Product> product = await readProductCart();
    for (var p in product) {
      subTotalCart += p.cantidad * p.precio;
    }
    setState(() {});
    return product;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: cartListView(cartData)  
              ) ,),),
            
             Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Subtotal: $subTotalCart',
                  ),],),)],),),);}}
```

```
Widget cartListView(cartData){
  return FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
    future:cartData, //fetchCartData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
        ? CartList(products: snapshot.data)
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  );
}
```

```
class CartList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Product> products;
  CartList({Key key, this.products, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CartListState createState() => _CartListState();
}

class _CartListState extends State<CartList> {
  onDelete(idProducto){
    print(idProducto);
    setState(() {
      widget.products.removeWhere((item) => item.idProducto == idProducto);
    });
    storeCart(widget.products);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount:  widget.products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final product = widget.products[index];
        int subtotalProducto = product.cantidad * product.precio;
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
               Container(
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                   TextData(data: 'Subtotal:',),
                   TextData(data: subtotalProducto.toString())
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                onPressed: () => onDelete(product.idProducto),
              )
            ],
          ),);},);}}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar la función de cartListView

Comment: Donde esta el código que muestra tu lista?, donde utilizas `CartList`? y supongo que donde muestras tu lista es en `cartListView` por lo que `CartList` no veo donde lo utilizas.

Comment: ya agregue cartListView

Comment: has probado agregar el `setState` en el `onPressed` donde quieres eliminar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo en lugar de hacer el evento dentro de tu widget, mandaría el onPressed hacia tu widget principal donde obtienes el listado, y desde ahí realizar la suma

Te dejo un ejemplo de https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/VwarNOo

Genero una función para realizar la suma, como no lo manejas en variable dentro de tu widget, entonces le paso el listado como parámetro.

```
_setTotal(List<Product> product) {
    subTotalCart = 0;
    for (var p in product) {
      subTotalCart += p.cantidad * p.precio;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

Future<List<Product>> fetchCartData() async {
    List<Product> product = await readProductCart();
    for (var p in product) subTotalCart += p.cantidad * p.precio;
    _setTotal(product);
    setState(() {});
    return product;
  }
```

En la función cartListView, donde envías el listado a tu clase le agrego un parámetro de la función, donde elimino el producto, y vuelvo a generar la suma.

```
_onDeleteItem(List<Product> products, int idProducto) {
  products.removeWhere((item) => item.idProducto == idProducto);
  _setTotal(products);
}

Widget cartListView(cartData) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
      future: cartData, //fetchCartData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? CartList(
                products: snapshot.data,
                ondeleted: (int item) => _onDeleteItem(snapshot.data, item),
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
```

Y a la clase CartList  le agrego un parámetro de función que sera el que bindeare en el evento onPressed.

```
class CartList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Product> products;
  final Function ondeleted;

  CartList({Key key, this.products, this.ondeleted}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CartListState createState() => _CartListState();
}


IconButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
  onPressed: () => widget.ondeleted(product.idProducto),
)
```

Comment: si me ayudo tu ejemplo, gracias amigo.